# React Native - Separate View and Logic

Tags: react-native

Is separate view and logic (like java class and xml in Android) in React Native is best way to increase app performance? Any reference for this guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of app performance it wont really matter because in the end it all gets combined into a single JS bundle file. But separating render and business logic is always useful. It lets you rewrite business logic without having to navigate render logic when you want to make a change and also helps reuse business logic elsewhere in your app if you need to.

A simple example is something we evaluated at work, we have a react native application and a react website. A lot of our business logic of API handling data parsing and storage and redux handling was similar if not exactly the same on both platforms. What we realised is that if we write all the business logic separately we could simply write it once and use it on both platforms and only our render logic could change. Now it is more complicated than my explanation of course but it is possible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks bro, it's very useful. umm, is there a library for separating logic from view bro?  @Nemi Shah

Comment: Well no there is not, and unfortunately there is not any easy way of separating logic if your app is close to being done We ended up having to refactor our code base sadly which took longer than we like to admit. But glad I helped.